# What is the difference between struct addrinfo and struct sockaddr

Tags: c, sockets, networking

From what I understand struct addrinfo is used to prep the socket address structure and struct sockaddr contains socket address information. But what does that actually mean? struct addrinfo contains a pointer to a struct sockaddr. Why keep them separate? Why can't we combine all things within sockaddr into addr_info?

I'm just guessing here but is the reason for their separation is to save space when passing structs? For example in the bind() call, all it needs is the port number and the internet address. So both of these are grouped in a struct sockaddr. So, we can just pass this small struct instead of the larger struct addrinfo?

```
struct addrinfo {
    int              ai_flags;     // AI_PASSIVE, AI_CANONNAME, etc.
    int              ai_family;    // AF_INET, AF_INET6, AF_UNSPEC
    int              ai_socktype;  // SOCK_STREAM, SOCK_DGRAM
    int              ai_protocol;  // use 0 for "any"
    size_t           ai_addrlen;   // size of ai_addr in bytes
    struct sockaddr *ai_addr;      // struct sockaddr_in or _in6
    char            *ai_canonname; // full canonical hostname

    struct addrinfo *ai_next;      // linked list, next node
};

struct sockaddr {
    unsigned short    sa_family;    // address family, AF_xxx
    char              sa_data[14];  // 14 bytes of protocol address
};
```

Answer (score 31, accepted):

`struct addrinfo` is returned by `getaddrinfo()`, and contains, on success, a linked list of such `struct`s for a specified hostname and/or service.

The `ai_addr` member isn't actually a `struct sockaddr`, because that `struct` is merely a generic one that contains common members for all the others, and is used in order to determine what type of struct you actually have. Depending upon what you pass to `getaddrinfo()`, and what that function found out, `ai_addr` might actually be a pointer to `struct sockaddr_in`, or `struct sockaddr_in6`, or whatever else, depending upon what is appropriate for that particular address entry. This is one good reason why they're kept "separate", because that member might point to one of a bunch of different types of `struct`s, which it couldn't do if you tried to hardcode all the members into `struct addrinfo`, because those different `struct`s have different members.

This is probably the easiest way to get this information if you have a hostname, but it's not the only way. For an IPv4 connection, you can just populate a `struct sockaddr_in` structure yourself, if you want to and you have the data to do so, and avoid going through the rigamarole of calling `getaddrinfo()`, which you might have to wait for if it needs to go out into the internet to collect the information for you. You don't have to use `struct addrinfo` at all.

Comment: is getaddrinfo() also more useful if you only know the hostname and not the ip address of the host? Because it seems kind of repetitive if you're the client (and you know the server's ip) and you call getaddrinfo and you send in the ip address of the server and getaddrinfo() returns a addrinfo struct with all the details you already know? this comment must just be re stating what you said..sorry

Comment: `getaddrinfo()` is sometimes convenient if you have the IP address in a *string* - say after it was entered at the command line. You could parse it yourself and get it into the 32 bit integral format required by `struct sockaddr_in`, but sometimes you might figure it's easier to let `getaddrinfo()` do it for you. If you already have the IP in a format you could drop into `struct sockaddr_in`, calling `getaddrinfo()` would usually be pretty pointless.