# How do I perform a DNS look-up using libuv?

Tags: c, dns, libuv

I am trying to use [libuv](/questions/tagged/libuv) to resolve a URL to an IP address. I am using the function `uv_getaddrinfo`, which passes an `addrinfo` object to my call-back.

Is this callback where I receive the IP address? How do I extract the IP address from the `addrinfo` object?

Comment: As this is C it's not really an "object", but a "structure". The difference might seem academic, but it's important from a programming perspective.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's [utility functions](http://docs.libuv.org/en/v1.x/misc.html?highlight=uv_ip4_name) geared towards this, like `uv_ipv4_addr` and `uv_ipv4_name` depending on what you want broken out of that structure.

Many LibUV functions take an `addrinfo` directly, so it's a useful structure to have.

---

libuv provides `uv_ipv4_name` and `uv_ipv6_name`. The function you choose depends on the `addrinfo` object you have:

```
if (addrinfo.ai_family == AF_INET) {
    // ipv4
    char c[17] = { '\0' };
    uv_ip4_name((sockaddr_in*)(addrinfo.ai_addr), c, 16);
    std::cout << c << std::endl;
} else if (addrinfo.ai_family == AF_INET6) {
    // ipv6
    char c[40] = { '\0' };
    uv_ip6_name((sockaddr_in6*)(addrinfo.ai_addr), c, 39);
    std::cout << c << std::endl;
}
```

You may get multple `addrinfo` structs from `uv_getaddrinfo`. These are stored a singly-linked list, where the "next" pointer is `addrinfo.ai_next`.

This is also helpful: [What is the difference between struct addrinfo and struct sockaddr](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23401147/what-is-the-difference-between-struct-addrinfo-and-struct-sockaddr)